# Intersection between elliptical parallel surface and line

Tags: euclidean-geometry, surfaces, solid-geometry

**Geometric situation**

Given is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is equidistant to an ellipse. There is no special name for this type of parallel surface but if the ellipse becomes a circle we get a torus. The surface can be parametrically defined by
$$
\begin{align}
    \vec{x} 
=  \begin{bmatrix}
a\cos u-b r \cos u\cos v \ \left(b^2\cos^2 u+a^2\sin^2 u\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
b\sin u- a r \sin u\cos v\ \left(b^2\cos^2 u+a^2\sin^2 u\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
r\sin v
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\tag{1}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the known ellipse's semiaxes, and $r$ is the known radius of the circular cross-section, with $r<(a,b)$. The free parameters $u,v$ can be limited to the range $[0,2\pi]$. There is also a line with known parameters $(m_i,n_i)_{i=1,2,3}$ and free parameter $t$ in the range $[-\infty,+\infty]$ with equation

$$
\begin{align}
    \vec{y} 
=  \begin{bmatrix}
m_1\\
m_2\\
m_3
\end{bmatrix}
+  t\begin{bmatrix}
n_1\\
n_2\\
n_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\tag{2}$$

Here's a plot of a possible situation (case 4 in the table below) where the line intersects twice the surface:

[image]

Mathematica Code of the plot:

```
a = 3; b = 1; r = 0.3;
s1 = ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u] - b r Cos[u] Cos[v]/Sqrt[b^2 Cos[u]^2+ a^2 Sin[u]^2], 
Sin[u] - a r Sin[u] Cos[v]/Sqrt[b^2 Cos[u]^2 + a^2 Sin[u]^2],
r Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Mesh -> 40];
s2 = ParametricPlot3D[{-3, 0, 0} + {-1, 0.2, -1} t, {t, -20, 10},
PlotStyle -> {Black,Thick}];
Show[{s1, s2}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-4, 2}}, Axes -> None,Boxed -> False]
```

**Question**

There are 6 different intersections scenarios.

$\small{\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{Case} & \text{tangents} & \text{secants} & \text{sum} \\ \hline
1    & 0        & 0       & 0   \\ 
2    & 1        & 0       & 1   \\
3    & 2        & 0       & 2   \\
4    & 0        & 2       & 2   \\
5    & 1        & 2       & 3   \\
6    & 0        & 4       & 4  
\end{array}}$

Task: Check only if the number of intersections is 0 or above 0, i.e. do we have case 1 or not?

I tried to find if there are one or several combinations of $u,v,t$ so that $\vec{x}=\vec{y}$ but got only very complicated expressions. Is there a closed expression or do I have to use iterative methods?

*Related question:*

[Shape defined by equidistant points to an ellipse in $\Bbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4187383/737314)

Comment: Want a numrical ode for a parallel to elliptical torus  meridian ?

Comment: What do you mean? ODE or Code? What is a parallel torus?

Comment: I meant ode . The code can be written next for Bertrand parallel surface  to an ellipse meridian.

Comment: If it solves the problem in the OP it would be interesting

Comment: OK, what is constant parallel offset distance to be given everywhere in Mathematica code?

Comment: What do you mean by offset distance?

Comment: constant normal distance between common surface normal

Comment: the offset distance is a variable, in the code above called r with r<(a,b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the original ellipse $\mathbf{p}(u)$ that the "elliptical torus" is parallel to.

$\mathbf{p}(u) = (a \cos u , b \sin u , 0) $

and consider also the line $\mathbf{q}(t)$,

$\mathbf{q}(t) = \mathbf{m} + t \mathbf{n}$

Find the distance between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$, then minimize it.

If the minimum is less than $r$, then you have at least $2$ intersections. If the minimum is greater than $r$, then there are no intersections.

To minimize the distance, consider the square of the distance,

$f (u, t) = (\mathbf{p}(u) - \mathbf{q}(t))^T (\mathbf{p}(u) - \mathbf{q}(t))$

At the minimum of $f$, we have $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \dfrac{\partial f }{\partial t } = 0 $

Thus, we have the following two equations:

$(\mathbf{p}(u) - \mathbf{q}(t))^T (- a \sin u ,  b \cos u, 0 ) = 0$

and

$(\mathbf{p}(u) - \mathbf{q}(t))^T (\mathbf{n} ) = 0$

These two equations can be solved for $u$ and $t$ using a numerical iteration such as the multivariate Newton-Raphson method, and it should converge to the solution very quickly (usually within 5 iterations).  Once you have $u$ and $t$ you can calculate the distance, and compare it with the radius $r$.

Comment: As usual this method finds a local minimum but not necessarily the needed global minimum. What would be an initial guess for start values to find always the global minimum?

Comment: I don't have proof of it, but I think once a minimum is found, it will be in this particular problem a global minimum.  If in your simulations you find a situation where two minimums are found, then one could possibly go through a scan of initial values of $t_0$ and $u_0$ over a certain range, and run the minimization for each case.

Comment: There are many case where no global minima are found. Test of different inititial values is not appropriate as speed is an issue, so one should have good initial start values.

Comment: I don't know of any way to select the initial values for $t_0$ and $u_0$ other than by trial and error.  It is a guaranteed way to finding the best initial guesses based on the value of the function at these initial guesses.  You do not have to run the minimization for all the initial guesses, just evaluate the distance function at each initial guess pair $(t_0, u_0)$ and select the pair the gives the minimum value of the distance function, and only then run the minimization.